# Gcloud App with Flask. Objects have incorrect references when called

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gcloud

I have created a very simple Flask app and deployed it to GCloud App.

I have instantiated a simple class called `TestClass` and then printed it to get the object reference (for debugging).

On my index.html page, I have a button, that when clicked, fires an Ajax call to the `/process-click` route. This should then print the same object reference – which is does most of the time. But once in a while, I get another reference printed out. For example:

```
<TestClass object at 0x3e0b7bd57a30>
<TestClass object at 0x3e0b7bd57a30>
<TestClass object at 0x3e0b7bd57a30>
<TestClass object at 0x3e0b7bd57a30>
<TestClass object at 0x3e0b7bd9a790> <- Different
<TestClass object at 0x3e0b7bd57a30>
<TestClass object at 0x3e0b7bd9a790> <- Different
<TestClass object at 0x3e0b7bd57a30>
<TestClass object at 0x3e0b7bd57a30>
<TestClass object at 0x3e0b7bd57a30>
<TestClass object at 0x3e0b7bd9a790> <- Different
<TestClass object at 0x3e0b7bd57a30>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this? Is it something GCloud or Flask related? It works fine locally – the same obj reference 100% of the time. I'm using Python 3.8. I have included my `main.py` for reference:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from TestClass import TestClass

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    return render_template('index.html')


test_class = TestClass()
print(test_class)

@app.route('/process-click', methods=['POST'])
def process_move():
    if request.form:
        print(test_class)
```

Comment: App Engine is scaling and you're getting object references from each (of 2) instances? If you applied more concurrent load to the service, you should see more instances created.

Comment: As explained by @DazWilkin the behavior is totally consistent with App Engine's scaling behavior. Notice that you can always manually control the number of instances associated with your application by adding the [manual_scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#manual-scaling) field to your app.yaml file. Do you have any additional doubts?

Comment: I’ll try the manual_scaling as you suggested. I don’t think I’m able to ensure it remains at just one though? The problem I have is when the object is called, it has a different state. So, the information in the state isn’t correct.

Comment: Applications in App Engine should in general be [stateless](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuration-files#design_considerations_for_instance_uptime), since hardware or software failures can cause early termination or frequent instance restarts.

Comment: Although with manual scaling the number of instances specified can run continuously regardless of the load level, you'll need to carefully plan the load the instance receives and design your app to gracefully handle any unexpected event since [instance uptime is not guaranteed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-instances-are-managed#instance_uptime).